# "At the end" or "in the end"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, time, at-in

Which is correct?

> I am planning to buy some property **at the end** of 2011.
>
> I am planning to buy some property **in the end** of 2011.

Comment: Related: [“At the beginning” or “in the beginning”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/at-the-beginning-or-in-the-beginning), [“At the beginning of the century” or “in the beginning of the century”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/at-the-beginning-of-the-century-or-in-the-beginning-of-the-century)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe 'at the end' is correct, as you are describing a specific point in time.

Comment: what is the grammar rule for at vs in ?

Comment: At an instant, in an interval.   At the end of June, In the last week of June.

Comment: Second that. +1

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/askaboutenglish/2009/06/090901_aae_end_page.shtml

Answer (score 6):

There is not really a grammatical rule that governs this as far as I know. It's really more a question of idiomatic usage.

One would use *at the end* when a specific period of time or an event is being referred to. It will almost always be followed by *of* and in the cases when it isn't, the *of* will be implicit. For example if we were at a concert, I could say

> I hope they play Possum at the end.

Here, the listener would essentially hear the sentence

> I hope they play Possum at the end of the show.

On the other hand, *in the end* is used to refer to a more abstract notion. I could say

> In the end, it doesn't really matter if they finish with something else instead.

In this usage, *in the end* doesn't add any significant meaning to the sentence. It is serving as a qualifier though. It's presence indicates that I might be *slightly* disappointed if I didn't get to see Possum but *in the end* I'll be happy either way.

Another example would be

> In the end, I'd be happy to see Harry Hood, Antelope or Divided Sky.

Here, I'm saying that as long as they play any of the songs mentioned, I'll be happy regardless of what they finish with.

So *in the end* is often used to say that something will change as time moves on and will eventually settle in some certain state.

Comment: "In the end" refers specifically to a *conclusion*, meaning the same as "in the long run", or "ultimately".

Comment: @Jon Purdy. _In the long run_ is a nice comparison. I'll clear up the last paragraph when I get the time. I think that _the end_ in this case refers to _the end of something changing_, e.g. in the end, the ball will be resting on the ground. _Conclusion_ seems to me to indicate the end of something specific.

Answer (score 0):

In this case at the end is the only proper answer.

'at the end' means you'll do something literally near the end of something

'in the end' is more like 'after all'